# Create dataframe in python from list

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have extracted multiple data from file and now I want to create a dataframe of my data of interest. I have tried following way:

```
anticodon = re.findall(r'(at.\w\w-\w\w)', line)
    for line in anticodon:
        anticod = line.replace('at ', '')

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [m_id], 'cod': [anticod]})
print df1
* similar way I have extraced m_id
```

But in output I only get last row of both columns not the entire column. How can I get complete data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `anticod` each time you iterate through `anticodon`, and thus you are left with it being the final value. You need to store each value, for example, you could create a list at the start `anticods = []` and in your for loop append to it:

```
anticods = []

anticodon = re.findall(r'(at.\w\w-\w\w)', line)
    for line in anticodon:
        anticod = line.replace('at ', '')
        anticods.append(anticod)

m_ids = []
#similar logic for m_id
```

To then convert it into a dataframe, pass your lists as the column values:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'id': m_ids, 'cod': anticods}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```